# SSh AWS Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I want to SSH AWS EC2 instance but by just only my computer, like SSH over the key. Only my computer can ssh into that instance. How can I configure it?
Thanks.

Comment: You can change you sshd config and allow only one user using "match" and change allowed method public key and password.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to achieve that is to setup security group of your instance so that only your IP can access the instance:

- [Rules to connect to instances from your computer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-local-access)

Answer (score 0):

As Marcin already answered, you should use security group to restrict access to your IP only. However, whenever you change the network, you have to manually edit that security group again.

One solution would be restrict access using mac address using firewall, something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't require you to frequently update your security groups with your IP address is to use [SSH through AWS Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-enable-ssh-connections.html). Using SSH through Session Manager works exactly like a normal SSH connection. The SSH through Session Manager solution works by creating an SSH tunnel through your Session Manager connection. You can [control access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-restrict-access-examples.html) to your instance using IAM by restricting which AWS users can call StartSession on your EC2 instance. In your case, you can configure access to Session Manager only to the IAM User you configure on your computer.

You may even want to consider using Session Manager on it's own because that also allows you to connect to your instance and run commands... but using SSH through Session Manager gives you the security benefits of Session Manager and the familiarity of SSH. Session Manager allows you to connect to your EC2 instance without opening inbound ports on your security groups so it is more secure from a networking point of view especially if you have a publicly reachable instance. It uses normal HTTPS traffic so your instance will only need outbound access to the SSM Session Manager endpoints.

More details on how SSM Session Manager works [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html).